# MYSQL find average time per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this called 'victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity'

```
PickerID|ObjectScanned|      StartTime     |        EndTime     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    |     Bin     |2020-02-17 03:46:58 | 2020-02-17 03:47:13  
   2    |     Bin     |2020-02-17 13:34:02 | 2020-02-17 13:34:27
```

I want to find the average amount of seconds for each day

I'm using this query to fetch one day but it is hard coded for one day I want every day

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `StartTime`, `EndTime`)) 
as time_in_seconds 
FROM `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity` 

WHERE `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity`.`EndTime` IS NOT NULL
AND `PickerID` = 2
AND  `EndTime` < '2020-02-18 00:00:01' 
AND `ObjectScanned` = 'Bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming start time and end time are on the same day:

```
SELECT DATE(StartTime), AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `StartTime`, `EndTime`)) 
as time_in_seconds 
FROM `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity` 
WHERE `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity`.`EndTime` IS NOT NULL
      `PickerID` = 2 AND
      `ObjectScanned` = 'Bin'
GROUP BY DATE(StartTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check on comparison of `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`

```
       SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `StartTime`, `EndTime`)) 
        as time_in_seconds 
       FROM `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity` 

       WHERE `victory_picker_picktask_scanactivity`.`EndTime` IS NOT NULL
              AND `PickerID` = 2
              AND  date(`EndTime`) =date(`StartTime`) 
              AND `ObjectScanned` = 'Bin'
```